# How to make statusbar transparent in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

My status-bar background color getting white color while trying to make it transparent.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <StatusBar
         animated={true}
         backgroundColor="transparent"
         barStyle={"dark-content"}
         translucent={true}
     />
     <View>
         ...
     </View>
   </SafeAreaView>
```

If I use the Status-bar background color as red or green, it is reflecting in the status bar. But while I am using status-bar background color as "transparent", it is showing some white color shadow. If I remove the background color tag, it is showing a grey color status bar.

Also I am using *paddingTop* in **navigationOption**.

while no background color mentioned:
[image: backgroundColor not mentioned in statusbar]

while red background color mentioned in status bar:

[image: backgroundColor: "red" in StatusBar]

while transparent background color of status bar:

[image: backgroundColor: "transparent" in StatusBar]

Version using:
react-native: 0.61.5

Comment: It looks like transparent since your background is white. Can you change your background to another color and try again? @PrantikMondal

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SickRanchez. I have tested by removing the complete view. only keeping status bar. Still, it is showing some grey color.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me

```
export default function App() {   return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="transparent"
      />
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>   ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement status bar use it in App.js. The problem is with the SafeAreaView according to my experience.  Here is a snippet from one of my projects.

```
export default function App() {   return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="transparent"
        barStyle={'dark-content'}
        translucent={true}
      />
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>   ); 
}
```